# Why does `npm init` Assume NPM Package Build?

Tags: npm

This is definitely a theoretical question, but why does running `npm init` ask a bunch of questions for setting up the fields below?

```
"name": "my-project-that's-definitely not going to npm",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC"
```

A very large percentage of us are using `npm` just for the package management aspect of it. It seems to me like there should be an option to not set it up as anything BUT a package manager, so just:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@whatever/somepackage": ">=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0",
},
```

The only justification I can think of is that a lot of people also use npm as a build tool, so this provides an entry point for running scripts. Is that correct? Are there other reasons?

P.S. I know I can use `-y` flag to default the fields, but that still creates them.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that `npm` foremost purpose is a package manager.
And being a package manager, it manages various aspect of a package.
Being a package, it means your code should be able to distribute and reuse by others.
Thus that's why basic information such as name, version, and license are needed.

And `npm init` is the best place and best time to declare those.

As you mention, you can use `npm init -y` to use default values so that you don't have to answer them.